# Passing params from Angular to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript, will-paginate

I have a Rails application, and am exposing an API to be used by an Angular front-end. I am using the *will-paginate* gem for
paging my large dataset. The gem expects a *:page* to be passed via the params.

The buttons on the page are working fine, and calling the *nextPage* or *prevPage* functions, but for some reason the params 
with the page number are not being passed to the Rails controller.

When the user presses the next or previous buttons, I wish to have the paeg of data delivered from the rails controller and refreshed on screen.

Related question: [Rails will_paginate gem with angular.js to do pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255407/rails-will-paginate-gem-with-angular-js-to-do-pagination)

**app/controllers/api/data_sources_controller.rb**

```
class Api::DataSourcesController < Api::BaseController
  def index
    Rails.logger.debug("index: datasources, page: #{params[:page]}")
    render json: Cosmic.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 50)
  end
end
```

**app/assets/javascripts/controllers/DatasetController.js.coffee**

```
angular.module('assaypipelineApp').controller "DatasetController", ($scope, $routeParams, $location, DataSet) ->
  $scope.currentPage = 1

  $scope.init = ->
    @panel_id = $routeParams.panel_id
    console.log("dataset init: #{@panel_id}")
    @datasetsService = new DataSet(serverErrorHandler)
    $scope.datasets = @datasetsService.all({page: $scope.currentPage})


  # pagination
  $scope.prevPage = ->
    console.log("prev #{$scope.currentPage}")
    $scope.currentPage-- if $scope.currentPage > 0
    $scope.datasets = @datasetsService.all({page: $scope.currentPage})


  $scope.nextPage = ->
    console.log('next')
    $scope.currentPage++
    $scope.datasets = @datasetsService.all({page: $scope.currentPage})
```

**app/assets/javascripts/services/DataSetService.js.coffee**

```
angular.module('assaypipelineApp').factory 'DataSet', ($resource, $http) ->
  class DataSet
    constructor: (errorHandler) ->
      console.log('dataset constructor')
      @service = $resource('/api/data_sources/:id',
        {id: '@id'},
        {update: {method: 'PATCH'}})
      @errorHandler = errorHandler

      # Fix needed for the PATCH method to use application/json content type.
      defaults = $http.defaults.headers
      defaults.patch = defaults.patch || {}
      defaults.patch['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'

    all: ->
      @service.query((-> null), @errorHandler)

    find: (id, successHandler) ->
      @service.get(id: id, ((data_set)->
        successHandler?(data_set)
        data_set),
       @errorHandler)
```

**In the view**

```
<ul class="pagination pull-right">
    page {{currentPage}}
    <li ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == 0}">
        <a href ng-click="prevPage()">« Prev</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="n in range(pagedItems.length)"
        ng-class="{active: n == currentPage}"
    ng-click="setPage()">
        <a href ng-bind="n + 1">1</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == pagedItems.length - 1}">
        <a href ng-click="nextPage()">Next »</a>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I solved it, with the help of this book: https://leanpub.com/angularails

The answer was actually quite simple.

```
# pagination
$scope.setPage = (newPage) ->
  newPage = 1 if newPage < 1
  $scope.currentPage = newPage
  $scope.getPage() 

$scope.getPage = () ->
  http =
     method: "GET"
     url: "/api/data_sources"
     params: 
         page: $scope.currentPage
  $http(http)
     .success (response) ->
       console.log(response)
       $scope.datasets = response
```

Comment: If anyone has a better way of doing this, please post it & I will accept it as the answer.

Comment: what is the successHandler? where you have defined in your code ? I downloaded some rails app where I have see the same type of and used successHandler to return the server response , but I am not sure where its defined